# How to return the argument, which the mock method was called with, as response?

Tags: java, mockito

Is it possible in Mockito to return the object that mocked method was called with? Without prior knowing what object it will be.

```java
@Mock
MyObjectRepository myObjectRepository;
...
when(myObjectRepository.save(any(MyObject.class))) //save method returns normally MyObject.class object
     .thenReturn(\\the object that method was called with);
```

I want to return the object that is passed to save method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work:

```java
when(myObjectRepository.save(any(MyObject.class)))
     .then(AdditionalAnswers.returnsFirstArg());
```

Comment: I tried it first with `.thenReturn(...)` and it failed, works perfectly with simply `.then(AdditionalAnswers.returnsFirstArg())` [link](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-additionalanswers#1-returning-the-first-argument)